# RF noob here, help with antenna extension & noise reduction keywords

Tags: rf, antenna, interference

I have a design restriction. I have 24-bit adcs on the same circuit as a 4g lte module and "i have been told" that the ~250mw (~24db) of the 4g module interferes with adc measurement , i was wondering if extending the antenna, lets say ~40cm (~1.5"), along with a steel machined case would help with the interference problems?

I know that my idea sounds a bit over the top, but I would like your help about any keywords i could use to google that scenario.

Comment: Schematics? General layout? Placing the 4G module itself away from the ADC might help.

Comment: I am still looking for them...

Comment: after a little bit of searching i believe that this is the module i will probably use [A7670X](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003141460106.html?)